# Openmeetings GUI Change

Tags: html, css, apache, user-interface, openmeetings

I would like to customize the GUI of Apache Openmeetings. I installed it currently in Centos 6.7 and would like to add some buttons, hyperlinks etc. in it's GUI. Can anyone guide me about this, where can I edit the code?
     I like to add a button to redirect it into any other website and also want to add a widget having browse button to upload files from my local machine to any destination folder in backend (At cento server).?

Answer (score 0):

You need the source code and then modify the changes and compile it again.

You will need to read: http://openmeetings.apache.org/source-repository.html and http://openmeetings.apache.org/BuildInstructions.html